# Pegar o nome dos arquivos enviados pelo formulário

Tags: php, array, wordpress

Estou tentando pegar o nome dos arquivos após o envio do formulário:

```
add_action('gform_after_submission_5', function ($entry, $form) {

    $file_url = $entry['5'];

    $filename = basename($file_url);

}, 10, 2);
```

Ao dar um `var_dump $file_url;` ele me retorna isto (estou subindo só um arquivo por enquanto):

> string(72) "["http://winds.local/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/stabbing312.jpg"]"

E ao dar um `var_dump $filename;` retorna isto:

> string(17) "stabbing313.jpg"]"

Como faço para que o $filename não pegue as aspas e o colchete?

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Ao fazer isso:

```
$foo = explode(",", $file_url[0]);

foreach ($foo as $teste) {
    echo $teste.'<br>';
}
```

Ele ainda retorna as URLs com os colchetes:

> ["http://winds.local/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/WOLVERINE-THE-X-MEN-11-AVX-Tie-In10.jpg"
>   "http://winds.local/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/stabbing324.jpg"]

Comment: Que? As aspas e colchetes não são o resultado da "Impressão" da variável com vardump?

Comment: @user5978 o problema é que o basename está considerando as aspas e o conchete no final como parte da URL. Deveria parar no jpg, mas ele inclui "]

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de var_dump. Tenta fazer isso:

```
echo $file_url[0];
```

Se a saída que você postou está completa, significa que há um array, contendo uma string

Mas se o conteúdo da string for: `"["http://winds.local/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/stabbing312.jpg"]"`. Você pode tentar remover os caracteres `"`,`[` e `]` da seguinte forma:

```
$file_url = substr($file_url,2,strlen($file_url)-2);
$file_url = substr($file_url,0,strlen($file_url)-2);

echo $file_url;
```

Você também pode usar `eval`, concatenando na string, uma atribuição em um array, depois pegando o valor da forma que sugeri inicialmente, mas creio que isso não seja muito seguro. Melhor extrair os caracteres no "braço".

Comment: OK, retornou ["http:\/\/winds.local\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/stabbing320.jpg"]

Comment: com echo? pegando o indice do array?

Comment: Não, só a string acima.

Comment: Verifiquei agora, se o conteúdo for texto, var_dump tem a mesma saída.

Comment: Quando eu jogo o $file_url[0] em uma variável e dou um foreach nela, retorna invalid argument

Comment: Ok, modifiquei a resposta. Acrescentei a solução para o que parece ser o problema real.

Answer (score 0):

se for o caso de um upload eu sempre pego dessa maneira:

```
$_FILES['arquivo']['name']
```